# html content from post request python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I did a POST request using Pyhton, and I got HTML in the response.
The HTML looks like what I can see directly using the browser, so it is ok. But, how can I get data from it, I mean, I would like to be able to get data I want by using things like "response.html.xpath('//myxpath')"

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Getting data from a response is the same no matter if it is a POST or a GET. Please show the code you have so far. What have you tried? Are you using `requests` or something else? Have you read the documentation that shows how to get data from the response?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting by `XPATH` using `beautifulsoup4`

refer to:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup/